# mips read string over multiple lines

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to read max 100 characters of input from a user and then reverse the input. My program should stop reading when Z is detected and should be able to read over multiple lines. Right now I can read input over one line and it works, I am just struggling with the multiline part. Here is what I have so far:

```
    .data
    buffer: .space 100
    str2:  .asciiz "\nYou wrote:\n"
    str1:  .ascii "Enter string (max 100 chars): "

    .text

    main:
    la $a0,str1 #Load and print string asking for string
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    li $v0, 8 #take in input
    la $a0, buffer #load byte space into address
    li $a1, 100 # allot the byte space for string
    move $t1, $a0 #save string to t1
    syscall

    la $a0, str2 #load and print “You wrote" string
    li $v0,4
    syscall


    la $a0, buffer #reload byte space to primary address
    li      $t2, 0  

    strLen:                     #getting length of string
    lb      $t0, buffer($t2)    #loading value
    add     $t2, $t2, 1
    bne     $t0, $zero, strLen
    sub     $t2, $t2, 1
    li      $v0, 11             #load immedialtey - print low-level byte

   Loop:
   la      $t0, buffer($t2)     #loading value
   lb      $a0, ($t0)
   syscall

   sub     $t2, $t2, 1
   bnez    $t2, Loop

   li $v0,10 #end program
   syscall
```

Comment: Since Z is marking the end of input, you should read character by character instead of a whole line.

Comment: @m0skit0 any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Read character is [syscall 12](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html)